# DateTime2 is driving me crazy

Tags: entity-framework, datetime2

I'm using EF 4 (model First) in my project .NET and I having hard troubles with the `DateTime` fields.

When I'll use `SaveChanges()` this exception is thrown:

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

I tried to use:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGB = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

but nothing new happens. I'll explode my computer if I don't fix it this night.

I need help, I don't want explode my computer =( 1 week trying solve it without success

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        ModeloContainer ctx = new ModeloContainer();
        Cliente cli = ctx.Cliente.Where( cl => cl.IdCliente == id).First();
        Contrato c = new Contrato();

        c.Descricao = this.txtDescricao.Text;
        c.FaturarPara = this.ddlFaturarPara.SelectedValue;
        c.Tolerancia =  Convert.ToInt32(this.txtSuspenderContratoEm.Text);
        c.PeriodoPagto = this.ddlPeriodoPagamento.SelectedValue;

       // DateTime dtExpiracao = this.txtExpiraEm.Text.Trim() == "" ?                                                                       Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001") : Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtExpiraEm.Text.Trim());
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo enGB = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt, enGB);

        c.ExpiraEm = dt; //Here is the problem! but I no have idea how fix it

        ctx.AddToContrato(c);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        this.SalvarServiços(c.IdContrato);
}
```

I know, there's so many questions like this here, but none of them solves my problem.

I want insert date like this in TextBox: `09/08/2012`

Comment: Try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259716/datetime2-conversion-in-ef4) if that doesn't help you, can you post your model/

Comment: Is there any other non-nullable `DateTime` field in your entity? If yes, it is source of your problem because EF is sending 1/1/0001 to that column. You can also use SQL profiler to check what values is EF trying to save to database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any problem with your `ExpiraEm` column.

What I suspect is that you have another (or more than 1) datetime field which is non-nullable, and since you're not providing any value for them, EF will pass `01/01/0001` for them, which is not acceptable by SQL server (SQL Server's minimum acceptable date is January 1, 1753). So you get this SQL Exception.

Similar situations have been encountered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1916441/337294) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1678474/337294).